# Relative sizes of pymunk forces

Tags: simulation, gravity, pymunk

In Pymunk, is the magnitude of gravity the same as the magnitude of apply_force_at_local_point or apply_force_at_world_point, relatively speaking. In other words, is the magnitude of gravity=(20,40) equal to the magnitude of apply_force_at_world_point((20,40),object's position).

I used the equation of motion, final position = initial position + intial velocity * time + 1/2 * acceleration * t^2, to test that. It turns out that these magnitudes are not equal. For instance, it took a force of (0,-7888) to equal gravity of (0,-1750).

I am trying to determine apply_force_at_world_point force that would equal/cancel out gravity. I know I can just set the body's gravity to zero to achieve that effect but my goal is to determine magnetic force that would be enough to levitate a magnet of given weight and magnetic strength.

How can I find the magnitude of force (without testing a bunch of random values) that would equal gravity.

I hope the information given is enough to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can see how the velocity of a body is updated in the Chipmunk source code: https://github.com/viblo/Chipmunk2D/blob/master/src/cpBody.c#L501

```
body->v = cpvadd(cpvmult(body->v, damping), cpvmult(cpvadd(gravity, cpvmult(body->f, body->m_inv)), dt));
```

Translated to Python/Pymunk this would be something like this:

```
body.velocity = body.velocity * damping + (gravity + body.force / body.mass) * dt
```

From this I think this should work to make a opposing force matching the gravity:

```
body.apply_force_at_local_point(-space.gravity * body.mass)
```

(I tested this in a simple simulation with some gravity and a ball shape/body and it seems to work as expected, instead of falling the ball stayed put)

Comment: Thank you so much, viblo. You are a godsend. One more question that is relevant here. When I say space.gravity=0,-10, does it mean the body will move "down" 10 units in the first second and then 20 units in the second second and so on just like acceleration works in real life. What role does dt play here, if any